# Playing a "lawful" card after the mah jong wish that does not fulfill the wish

Tags: tichu

just getting into tichu and i'm confused about one thing. when someone plays the mah jong card and creates a wish for a 5 for example, and the next person does not have a 5, the rules say even if that next person does not have a 5 that they can play a lawful card or pass. does that mean if they don't have a 5, they can play a 6? then it goes on to say that the wish remains until someone plays a 5. so after that person plays a 6, can someone play a 5? or no, since that's not of a higher rank than 6?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: yes, if you do not have a 5, then you cannot fulfill the wish and you can play any legal play instead, including a 6.

For your second question: no, a player cannot play a 5 after a 6 has been played.

The wish does not exempt players from making only legal plays.

If you're currently playing single cards and a single 6 has been played, then no one can legally play a 5 (except in a bomb), because you can only play cards higher than 6.

The wish will remain in effect until someone can legally fulfill it.

> When a player plays the Mah Jong, he is allowed to wish for
> a certain rank (for example an 8 or an Ace, but not a special
> card). The next player who has a card of the desired rank,
> and can lawfully play it, must play it (possibly in a bomb! or
> rarely in a sequence). A player who does not hold or cannot
> play a card of the desired rank can play any lawfull card or
> pass.
> The wish remains in force until someone fulfils it.

[Source](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/f4/75/98-tichu-rulebook.pdf)